# metal flexing sound from 2nd floor

Tags: floor, sounds

I bought my home 6 months ago. When we moved in last summer, we didn't hear this sound.
Now when I step on particular spot on this one bedroom, I hear metal flexing sound. I am guessing the duct is installed too closely to the floor.

I don't use forced air heating.

A few questions:

1. Is there a way to eliminate or reduce the sound?
2. Why didn't i hear this in the summer? This is very loud noise so if it was there, I must have heard it but it started happening in October. 
   I live in Seattle where winter isn't too cold like in Michigan.

thanks

Comment: If you don't use forced air, what duct do you think it is? Dryer? Exhaust fan?

Comment: we do have forced air heating it is just that we never turn it on because we bougt electric heater from costco.